# How to make a break line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In java I send **30 frames (30 Strings)** using:

```
for(Frame frame : frames) {
    response.getWriter().write(frame.toString());
}
```

And I fetch it in my Ajax Post request as:

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML = '<br>' + result ;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="logs" class="text-center" style="margin-top: 25px;">

</div>
```

But I get all the lines **mixed into 18 lines**. Seems like the `<br>` doesn't work.

How can I exactly print each String in each line of the HTML?

Comment: You could enclose each string in `p` tags

Comment: You're adding a single `<br>` at the start of the entire 30 lines. How is that supposed to add line breaks in between lines?

Comment: i thought you ajax got the lines one by one. Seems like I'm wrong then

Comment: @Tiago in that case you'd need to append the new results with `+=` not assign with `=`

Comment: Can you try this... `document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML = '<br>' + result.split("\n").join("<br/>");`  It's a bit of a guess without knowing for sure what the response data is, but it may well solve your problem.

Comment: Alternatively change this line ... `response.getWriter().write("<br />" + frame.toString());`

Comment: What ajax gets depends on which resource it loads. If the resource contains 30 lines, AJAX will load 30 lines.

Comment: @Archer **that's the solution**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 alternatives.  First, you can add the line breaks when you build the response in your Java method...

```
response.getWriter().write("<br />" + frame.toString());
```

or (depending on whether you need to prepend or append the line breaks)

```
response.getWriter().write(frame.toString() + "<br />");
```

Secondly, you could split the response (assuming their are line breaks) and rejoin with Html line breaks, using Javascript...

```
document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML = '<br>' + result.split("\n").join("<br/>");
```

The second option depends on the format of the response data, so the first option is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

As "Nick A" mentioned in his comment, you should append new result to the contents of your `<div>` element instead of replacing it. So your Ajax function should be something like this (`=` replaced with `+=`):

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML += '<br/>' + result ;
}
```

**Edit:**
The main issue is that you're appending all data to the result on your server without putting any delimiter so that you could separate them on the client. You can also try adding the `<br/>` on your server side code as below:

```
for(Frame frame : frames) {
    response.getWriter().write(frame.toString() + "<br/>");
}
```

and then use your original ajax function on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `result` is just one big string that contains the string representation of any given `frame`, you just missed adding a new line here:

```
for(Frame frame : frames) {
    response.getWriter().write(frame.toString() + '<br/>');
}
```

I prepared two short examples for you:

**What you currently do:**

```js
var p = document.getElementById('myP');
var frames = new Array('FrameA', 'FrameB', 'FrameC');
var result = '';

// append each frames without adding a new line 
for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
 result += frames[i];
}

p.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p id="myP"></p>
```

**What you want to do:**

```js
var p = document.getElementById('myP');
var frames = new Array('FrameA', 'FrameB', 'FrameC');
var result = '';

// appending the frames with adding newlines
for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
 result += frames[i] + '<br/>';
}

p.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p id="myP"></p>
```